# Is there any command line profiling tool for cuda in ubuntu?? (Something like parallel Nsight)

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nsight

Can anyone tell me about any profiling tool for cuda which can be used on command line in ubuntu?? I am working on SSH secure Shell Client to run my programs on a remote linux machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a normal cuda 5 install, the [command-line profiler called nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview) should be available.  Try typing `nvprof` at a command prompt to see if it's available and set up.  But it's not a graphical tool like parallel nsight.  (There is also the original [command line profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#compute-command-line-profiler-overview))

However, if you are connected from a linux machine to your remote machine running cuda, and you have a normal cuda 5 install on the remote machine, and you connect with X-forwarding (ssh -X or ssh -Y) you should be able to run the [visual (graphical) profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) remotely.  You do not need X to be running on the remote machine, but it has to be running on your local machine.  After you connect with x-forwarding, just type `nvvp` in a terminal.  Note that running the visual profiler this way can be slow due to the X-forwarding, so be patient.  If you have the option to connect instead via something like NoMachine NX (or OpenNX on the mac) you will generally get faster performance when running nvvp remotely like this.